# Keybinding on Lubuntu

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, key-binding, lubuntu, xmodmap

I would like to bind few keys to the characters "\" "{" "}" on my 32 bits Lubuntu Netbook. I was able to do it using Xmodmap :

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 135 = backslash slash"
xmodmap -e "keycode 48 = leftbrace colon"
xmodmap -e "keycode 51 = rightbrace exclam"
```

However it resets as soon as I shut down the computer. How could I make it permanent? Or should I use another method?

I tryed to install Obkey which is designed for OpenBox, but meh nothing happens when I try to install it.

Please don't be rude I'm not so much familiar to Linux

Comment: You can put the commands into a script in `/etc/init.d/`. Try adding them to the `start)` case in `/etc/init.d/x11-common` (at least that's what it's called in Ubuntu 16.04). You'll need root privileges to do this, and of course make a copy of the original file before you change anything, so that you can just copy back the original in a recovery boot if things go disastrously wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please add some details? I'm new to Linux and I don't figure out how to create a script to run at boot

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ at the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Answer (score 0):

Open a "terminal" - either find it in the menus or press and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> and hit <kbd>T</kbd> (on Ubuntu).

Then at the **$** prompt type:

> sudo nano /etc/init.d/x11-common

... and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. - **sudo** will ask for your password and the run **nano** as the root user, as this is required for saving changes in the named file.

Use the arrow keys to move down almost to the end of the text, ...

Here:

```
case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ "$VERBOSE" != no ]; then
      log_begin_msg "Setting up X socket directories..."
    fi
    set_up_dir "$SOCKET_DIR"
    set_up_dir "$ICE_DIR"
    if [ "$VERBOSE" != no ]; then
      log_end_msg 0
    fi
  ;;
```

To do this nicely, create a copy of the following lines up to ";;" without including that line:

- At the line saying " start)", leave the cursor on the **first column
  of the next line**.
- Mark the text to be copied: Hit <kbd>esc</kbd> then
  <kbd>a</kbd>, then move the cursor to the first column of the line
  with ";;". *(You should see an expanding reversal of the text while doing this)*
- With the text marked, hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>k</kbd>...
  the marked text disappears... now re-insert it, and a copy by; hold
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>u</kbd> TWICE (for two copies).

Now you have a copy of text that you may edit for your needs, my way to do it:

- change the text between the quotes in `"Setting up X socket directories..."` (the line with log_begin_msg) to anything you find suitable.
- Then place the cursor on the lines with `set_up_dir`, hold
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>k</kbd> to delete each of them.
- To insert nicely indented lines; first activate "auto indentation" by hitting <kbd>esc</kbd> and then <kbd>i</kbd>. Now insert a line; move the cursor LEFT ONCE so that it ends up immediately after the `fi` on the previous line, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add a new line.
- Now type one of your commands, then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again for the next...
- When you have typed in all of your commands; hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and
  hit <kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano, **and answer Y to save the file**.

You should now be back at the **$** prompt...
To close the terminal, type `logout` (and hit Enter), hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>d</kbd>, or click the "x" in the window border to close the window.